# Why do we need the last two definitions for the grammar production base-specifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, derived-class

In [[class.derived.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#general-1) we have the following definitions for *base-specifier*:

*base-specifier*:
    *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> class-or-decltype*
    *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `virtual` *access-specifier<sub>opt</sub> class-or-decltype*
    *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> access-specifier* `virtual`*<sub>opt</sub> class-or-decltype*

Why do we need the second **and** the third definitions above? Why is the `virtual` required in the second definition while it's optional in the third?

Comment: I think its difficult to express that `virtual` can come before or after _"access-specifier"_ but not both before and after; any other way. So `virtual public virtual` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need the second and the third definitions above?

Syntactic sugar. Thanks to this, both `class Derived: public virtual Base` and `class Derived: virtual public Base` are valid. Much better than having to look up the order once a year when virtual inheritance is needed.

> Why is the `virtual` required in the second definition while it's optional in the third?

Note that second option has obligatory `virtual` and third option has obligatory *access-specifier*. Thanks to this, both `class Derived: virtual Base` and `class Derived: public Base` are valid. And it makes it possible to have the advantage above, as opposed to defining it as
    *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `virtual`<sub>opt</sub> *access-specifier<sub>opt</sub> class-or-decltype*

Perhaps it could be formulated in a different way, but I can't think of anything better to express those two aspects.